# AkkaHttpClient: Equivalent of socketTimeout

Tags: akka, akka-http

We have 3 timeouts in Apache-HttpClient:

```
HttpClients.custom()
    .setConnectionManager(cm)
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(...)
            .setSocketTimeout(...)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(...)
    .build();
```

Which:

- Connection Timeout: The time to
  establish the connection with the remote host the
- Socket Timeout: The time waiting for data, after establishing the connection; maximum time of inactivity between two data packets

But AkkaHttpClient only has `connecting-timeout` and doesn't have any configuration property for `Socket Timeout`. Is There any equivalent prop **or way** for setting a default `Socket Timeout` for requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for timeouts in the client beyond the connecting-timeout, the recommendation is to use the various Akka Streams operators (e.g. `idleTimeout`), which give you far more control.

There is also a [general idle timeout](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/timeouts.html#connection-level-idle-timeout) which will close connections if nothing is sent or received: this is intended as a global safety feature, so it can't be configured per-request.